# Avoid N+1 Queries in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How to eager load the data

i have three models called City, User, Bank

so i need to eager load the data to avoid N+1 Queries

here in my method of city.rb

def update_data(activity = false) # Used in delayed Job
# Filtering the Users

```
#here i need to filter the users based on the activity

#if the activity is true then i need to fetch all the users of the city
else i need to fetch the users who belongs to the city where the bank of the user has enabled_banking flag false and those user who dont have any bank

so i have written a query like 



 filtered_users = activity ? users : users.left_joins(:banks).where("(banks.enabled_banking = ?) OR (banks.id IS NULL)", false)
```

#then

```
filtered_users.find_in_batches do |city_users|
  city_users.each do |user|
    user.format_and_process
  end
end
```

end

but i need to avoid n+1 queries in both cases,  fetching all the users and also when i append the left join to fetch the records.

How to achieve this

previously i updated like

```
users.includes(:city, :bank)
```

then

```
 filtered_users = activity ? users : users.left_joins(:banks).where("(banks.enabled_banking = ?) OR (banks.id IS NULL)", false).references(:banks)
but this will not the optimzed way to fetch the records.


How we can achieve this expected behaviour?
```

Comment: filtered_users.includes ought to do it.  Maybe include the fetches that are actually happening in the ticket.  I usually use https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet to investigate these - it does a pretty good job.